# Typescript/prototype directly onto d3 object and d3-context-menu

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript

I'm using typescript and I'm able to use d3 v4 just fine with a wild card import.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

I'd like to use d3-context-menu within my project as well but I'm not really sure where to begin integrating the context menu plugin with regular d3 so I can just make call like their documentation shows.

```
.on('contextmenu', d3.contextMenu(menu))
```

I have the context menu plugin installed properly within the project and I can import it to the typescript file I'm working in, I just don't know how to properly connect everything together so the compiler will work and see the context-menu plugin as part of d3...

Comment: In looking at that plugin, I only see it as having examples with v3. I'm not sure if it's more of a TypeScript thing or rather a version thing (I'm using vanilla JS and it isn't working for me).

Comment: Yes, as of today the d3-context-menu is v3 only and will probably not work with d3.v4. Also there are currently no type definitions for d3-context-menu. All TypeScript cares about are those type definitions, unless d3-context-menu is natively in TypeScript, wich it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

There's a demo on the github page for this repo that only needed a bit of tweaking to get working for my purpose.

The trick was to add `.style('position', 'absolute')` to `d3.select('.d3-context-menu')`

It does need more significant work to get nested context menu's to work, but for top level it works fine.

[Modified Demo with D3 v5.14.2](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/1cn1Cq9zal0OkPzI?preview)

I realize this is an old post and it doesn't address typescript, but its not very hard to write your own typing file for the usage of this plugin